# Change cluster manager's item icon programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps

On my map I use the `Marker Cluster Utility` to group the markers. All the markers when first put on the map have the same icon, then, when I move close to one of the markers, its icon must change. I've read other discussions about this, but as far as I've understood, I'd need to remove the marker and generate it again with the new icon.

My markers belong to a cluster, so I should remove the marker from the cluster, generate a new marker and add it to the cluster manager object.

The problem is that the cluster manager object has a renderer attached to it which also defines the marker's icon and it would use the same icon as for the removed marker.

Some code:

the renderer class

```
class VenueMarkerRender(private val context: Context, map: GoogleMap, clusterManager: ClusterManager<Venue>)
    : DefaultClusterRenderer<Venue>(context, map, clusterManager) {

    override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: Venue?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions)

        markerOptions!!.icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context, R.drawable.ic_map_black))
    }

    override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<Venue>?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions)

        markerOptions!!.icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context, R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp))
    }

    override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<Venue>?): Boolean {
        return cluster!!.size > 1
    }

    /**
     * Takes a vector image and make it available to use as a marker's icon
     */
    private fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, @DrawableRes vectorDrawableResourceId: Int): BitmapDescriptor {
        // ...

        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

the Venue class

```
class Venue : ClusterItem {
    private var mPosition:   LatLng
    private var mTitle:      String? = null
    private var mSnippet:    String? = null

    constructor(lat: Double, lng: Double, title: String, snippet: String) {
        mPosition = LatLng(lat, lng)
        mTitle = title
        mSnippet = snippet
    }

    override fun getPosition(): LatLng {
        return mPosition
    }

    override fun getTitle(): String {
        return mTitle!!
    }

    override fun getSnippet(): String? {
        return mSnippet
    }
}
```

finally how the cluster manager is created and how a venue is added to it

```
mClusterManager = ClusterManager(this, map)
val renderer = VenueMarkerRender(this, map, mClusterManager!!)
mClusterManager!!.renderer = renderer

// other code

for (i in 0 until markers.length()) {
    val marker = JSONObject(markers.getJSONObject(i).toString())

    val venue = Venue(
            marker.getDouble("lat"),
            marker.getDouble("lng"),
            marker.getString("title"),
            marker.getString("snippet"),
    )

    mClusterManager!!.addItem(venue)
}

mClusterManager!!.cluster()
```

Is it possible to generate a new Venue object with its own icon and to add it to the cluster manager object? Or is there a better way to obtain what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the solution, I hope this will help someone else.

I've declared the renderer as a class attribute to make it available everywhere inside the activity

```
private var renderer: VenueMarkerRender? = null
```

before it was a private variable inside the method which sets up the `Cluster Manager`. Then it is initialized as already shown in the previous message

```
renderer = VenueMarkerRender(this, map, mClusterManager!!)
```

Now to change the marker when I get close to it, it is enough to call this method each time that the location changes

```
private fun markerProximity() {
    // get the venues' list from the cluster
    val venues = mClusterManager!!.algorithm.items

    // if the cluster was not empty
    if (venues.isNotEmpty()) {
        // initialize the array which will contain the distance
        val distance: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(0f,0f,0f)

        // loop through all the venues
        for (venue:Venue in venues) {
            // get the distance in meters between the current position and the venue location
            Location.distanceBetween(
                    venue.position.latitude,
                    venue.position.longitude,
                    lastLocation.latitude,
                    lastLocation.longitude,
                    distance)

            // if closer than 3 meters
            if ( distance[0] < 3 ) {
                // change this marker's icon
                renderer!!.getMarker(venue)
                          .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                          .fromResource(R.drawable.my_location))
            }
        }
    }
}
```